# Google Webmaster tool complains about blocked URL, but it isn't

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, wordpress

We have recently integrated with google webmaster tools.

Now, on one of the pages, google complains:
**Indexed, though blocked by robots.txt**

Our robots.txt looks like this:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Allow: /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php


Sitemap: http://<domain>/sitemap.xml.gz
```

So, if I understand how it works, all the rest of the URL (except /wp-admin/) should not be blocked.

Why am I getting this warning?

Comment: Nothing you have said so far looks out of place.   Have you updated robots.txt recently?   Is the page on a subdomain?   Does `http:` vs `https:` match what you would expect?

Comment: Well, we just published it several days ago, and it only started indexing

Comment: And we still don't have ssl installed, so that part should be fine

Comment: What was on the domain before this site you published a few days ago?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Another wordpress installation with robots.txt blocking everything. But, we never added it to webmaster tools before.

Comment: What do you see in the SERPs for this URL/page?

Comment: @MrWhite sorry, I am not sure what is SERP

Comment: Which page is blocked? Try putting it in the url inspection tool and then doing a live test.

Comment: SERP is an abbreviation for the Search Engine Results Page. If the page is blocked by `robots.txt` then this is also reflected in the SERPs, as you will get the message "A description for this result is not available because of this site's robots.txt", where you would normally see the _description_. If you are not then it suggests it is an erroneous report in GSC. (Btw, it's not been called "Google Webmaster Tools" for almost 4 years now.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that you recently updated your *robots.txt* file.   It may take several months for Google to crawl all your pages again and realize that they are no longer blocked by *robots.txt*.

Even though you had never signed up for Google Search Console with your old site, Google was still collecting data about it.   Now that you have signed up for GSC, Google is showing you everything that you would have seen had you signed up previously.  Your new site data will be mixed in with your old site data.

You may see other remnants of your old site as well:

- Links in the external links report that were created for your old site
- Crawl errors from URLs that used to be on your old site
- Search analytics data from before you signed up for Google Search Console

Comment: I also had this problem. Took me 47 days to get it sorted in the Google Search Console. OP, if you are facing this issue in the GSC, do the fixes and give time to the crawl bot. That's all.

Comment: "...several months for Google to crawl all your pages again" - this also implies the URL existed on both the old site ("another WordPress installation") and the new one. (Assuming this URL does exist on the new site and it's not simply a hangover from the old site?!)

Comment: If the page is not on the new site it would change from showing as "indexed, blocked by robots.txt" to "not indexed - 404 not found crawl error."